# In ed (line editor), how to create a new file for editing?

Tags: ed

I'm not able to open a new-file for editing in the standard line-editor, ed.
I'm able to open an existing file though.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error I get]

The user guide I'm referring says, ed should return '?barney' i.e ?[new_file_name]; however in my case it searches for existing files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `w`rite it. `ed` will create the file for writing:

```
$ ed fred
fred: No such file or directory
w
0

?
q
$ ls fred
fred
```

Answer (score 0):

The text you are reading is likely written for some other implementation of `ed`.  Diagnostic output is only partially consistent across all implementations of the editor. The editor you are using behaves as one would expect a current implementation to act, i.e., it outputs a short diagnostic message about `barney` not being found and places you in "command mode".  Apart from the details about what the diagnostic message *says*, this is the same as in your text.

---

The `ed` editor has the notion of "the default filename".  When you start the editor using `ed barney`, the default filename is `barney`.  When you write the buffer to the file using `w`, the file named by the default filename is overwritten by the buffer.  If the file does not exist, it will be created.

You set the default filename from the command line as shown above and in your question, but you may also set it with the `f` command.  With no argument, the `f` command print the default filename to the terminal:

```bash
$ ed -p '*' myfile
myfile: No such file or directory
*f
myfile
*f my-other-file
my-other-file
*w
0
*q
```

```bash
$ ls -l my-other-file
-rw-r--r--  1 myself  myself  0 Nov 17 11:41 my-other-file
```

If there is no default filename (you started the editor without naming a file), you need to either set the default filename with `f somename` before writing the file with `w`, or you may give the filename to `w` as an argument.  Using `w` with a filename argument sets the default filename to that name if there is no default filename set.

`w myfile` changes the default filename here:

```bash
$ ed -p '*'
*w
?
*w myfile
0
*f
myfile
*q
```

`w bar-file` does *not* change the default filename here (as it's already set on the command line):

```bash
$ ed -p '*' foo-file
foo-file: No such file or directory
*w bar-file
0
*f
foo-file
*q
```